# 'Incorrect type warnings' for TypedDicts in unittest assertDictEqual

Tags: python, types, python-unittest, python-typing

I'm writing some unit tests for a function I've made and the `self.assertDictEqual(expected, actual)` is giving me a warning for incorrect typing.

```
Expected type 'Mapping[Any, object]', got 'CustomFooBarDict' instead
```

The unit tests run fine but I was wondering if there's a way to tell unittest that this is a `TypedDict` so not to worry, it's still a mapping, but it's from `string` to `string`s, `int`s and a couple of `Enum`s which are all par for the course with your standard `dict`.

For example, in TypeScript I would be able to use the `as` keyword to tell the transpiler not to worry.

Example here:

```py
import typing
import unittest

class FooBarStruct(typing.TypedDict):
    foo: str
    bar: int

def create_foo_bar_struct() -> FooBarStruct:
    return {'foo': 'baz', 'bar': 1}

class TestFooBarStruct(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo_bar(self):
        expected: FooBarStruct = {'foo': 'baz', 'bar': 1}
        self.assertDictEqual(expected, create_foo_bar_struct())
```

I've verified this minimum reproducible example in VSCode. As I mentioned, the tests run, but the warnings are there and when I am running my pipeline I don't want any warnings.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that will cause this error?

Comment: Hi there @DaniilFajnberg - I've added it to the question, thanks

Comment: Do you mean you see warnings in your IDE? Because I don't get any from the interpreter. If so, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: In any case, there is nothing wrong with your code (typing or otherwise) that I can see. You can [see here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=2785487dc064f926dfd41cea90084f07) that `mypy --strict` agrees. So any IDE warnings about incorrect types have to do with bugs in that IDE's internal type checker.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DaniilFajnberg - I'm not sure it's a bug with VSCode but I've found that using `self.assertEqual` works without the warning, just won't give as nice of a diff if the tests fail

Comment: It is actually fairly simple. _"any TypedDict type is consistent with `Mapping[str, object]`"_ (see [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency)) And `TestCase.assertDictEqual` expects the arguments to be of type `Mapping[Any, object]`. (see [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/unittest/case.pyi)) Ergo, what you did is correct.